# Seeking clever method to pin box to concrete

Tags: plumbing, concrete

[An Irrigation Control box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/NDS-14-in-x-19-in-Standard-Valve-Box-Extension-with-ICV-Overlapping-Cover-115/100377392?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-205220755-_-100377392-_-N) was cut out to house a set of outdoor piping:

[image]

I would like to strongly fasten the box to the wall, `because the when the cover is taken off it will tug the box away from the wall`.  For some reason there is a threaded hole in the box.

[image]

I have considered 90 degree angle iron to pin the box in place, however I thought that I would run this problem by the community before committing to a solution.

Comment: "some reason" would appear to be "to hold the cover on" (or to allow holding the cover on) just looking at the parts.

Answer (score 1):

Your box is not big enough. Assuming your box is big enough to go around the pipes and still leave a nice section of flange to bolt to the wall, your question becomes "How to I bolt something to a stucco wall?".

If the stucco is real, use blue (Tapcon) bolts made for cement. Get the size that says to use a 3/16 inch hole (one size up from the thinnest), then drill a 5/32 inch hole (the size recommended for the thinnest). What I usually do is get both sizes of blue bolts. If the thin one strips, then use the fatter one in the same hole. Repeat once hole vs material vs screw is found. If the bolt gets tight before it goes all the way in, then the bolt is to long. Once you unscrew a blue bolt, then it will have to go in deeper or be a fatter bolt.

Good luck. The building finish appears somewhat crackly. You should use a battery powered hammer drill if the wall is brittle.

And yes, do get a bigger box. **Which way does the handle of that left-most valve turn?** Is it possible to turn the shut off with this box in place? A tight situation is not a good situation, especially if this is a place where someone else might want to open this box.

Even better -- **forget that box** -- forget those bolts. Build a four sided cube out of treated wood where the back and the bottom are open, then half-bury it in the ground to hold it in place. Consider making something. The box you have in your hand is all wrong. How about putting a chair over there? Consider the goal. Physically protect the pipes and possibly add insulation for the winter time. I assume that is the goal. Your imagination is the only limit for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just drill a few holes in the bottom flange and use whatever masonry anchors you like - Ramset for quick and hard to undo, Tapcons, anchors and regular screws in suitable sized holes. I might choose stainless steel screws just for the sake of being able to expect to remove it later, myself.

I'm pretty sure your threaded hole is for a bolt to hold the cover on. Which you'll probably need to keep the cover from opening on its own, since it's not flat in the ground.